# Make correct dragging through several objects

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mouseover, drag

I make a javascript leaflet project. I have 2 type of markers. The first one is for car-stop and the second one is for waypoint.

The goal is to drag car-stop marker and move it through some waypoint markers. (From 0 to n) Without dropping.

After dragend, car-stop marker returns in start position, and add to parent all objects that this marker moving throw.

So i make events. On:

dragstart(car-stop point marker): define global object to add,

mouseover(waypoints): add "this" to global object, if global object !null,

dragend(car-stop point marker): stop and make global object null,

It works.
But the problem is that it works only when dragging of car-stop marker is "fast". If did it slowly, mouseover didnt fired.
May be i chose wrong way to achieve the goal, or may be you know. how to make it better?

```
 tmpVar = L.marker([point.LAT, point.LON], {
                'title': title,
                'draggable': true
            });

 tmpVar.on('mouseout', function(event){
                var localData;
                localData=event.target.source.NUMBER-1;
                if (typeof(rootScope.addingPoints) != "undefined"){
                rootScope.addingPoints.push(localData);
               }
            });


  tmpVar2 = L.marker([track[i].coords[0].lat, track[i].coords[0].lon],
  tmpVar2.on('dblclick', function(event){
                    var localData=event.target;
                    rootScope.$emit('pointEditingPopup', localData );
                });

  tmpVar2.on('dragstart', function(event){
                rootScope.addingPoints=[];
                if( typeof (event.target.source.servicePoints) == 'undefined'){
                event.target.source.servicePoints=[];
                }
                    rootScope.currentStopPoint=event.target.source;
                });

  tmpVar2.on('dragend', function(event){
                var container=event.target;
                checkAndAddNewWaypointToStop(rootScope.addingPoints, rootScope.currentStopPoint);
                container.setLatLng([container.source.lat, container.source.lon]).update();  
                });
                addMarker(tmpVar2);
```

Comment: Show us what you've done so far and we may be able to help, with no code there's no way you'll get a decent answer.

Comment: Complete.
I think case isnot in code, but in method of solve.